# What accent does David Gower speak with?

Tags: accent

[According to this meta post accent questions, especially those that are well researched and about real-life public figures are on topic.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/accent-identification-questions)

I'm just curious as to what accent the English cricket commentator David Gower speaks with. I see from his wiki page he was born in Kent but that page says nothing about where he was educated. The sounds he makes sure is pleasant.

[PS - Here is a link, copyright should be OK looks like an official youtube channel.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csu8beYBUqI)

Comment: I wouldn't put him quite as 'ultra-standard' as say Sir Ian McKellen as Gandalf trying to sound like Tolkien himself, or Stephen Fry as Jeeves, but a strong and perhaps unexpected dollop of Oxbridge while retaining a nice hint of a Kentish perhaps via Tanganyika (almost Ozzie) edge. And nowadays less prone to be caught out in slips.

Comment: Edwin that sounds like an answer, would you please post it as such?

Comment: People like Gower aren't particularly useful in terms of identifying ***real*** regional and/or class-based accents, because of their highly mobile backgrounds (although "well-spoken", Gower is something of a "linguistic mongrel").

Comment: Sorry, Neil, I've no supporting material, so regard it as not authoritative enough to be submitted as an 'answer'.

Comment: Southern RP with maybe a very faint hint of Estuary. He was born in Dar-Es-Salaam when it was the capital of Tanganyika and lived there until he was 6 so he has a slight British East Africa twang.

Comment: He actually discusses his accent, and whether or not it sounds "posh," in [this interview starting at 4:44](https://youtube.com/watch?v=CR7K45vG92g&t=4m44s). He more or less says that he switches between more posh and less posh ways of speaking depending on context.